# Check WebView's URL while Unit Testing in Robotium

Tags: java, android, url, webview, robotium

Im trying to figure out the easiest way to check my Main Activity's URL inside my (WebView). This is going to be in a Unit Test using the Robotium 4.1 framework. All i am trying to figure out how i can interact with the webview, such as send the activity a URL to load, so i can test against that and make sure the correct URL is loaded and also check my actionbar items as well.

Any Codes, suggestions or recommendations would be highly appreciated.

```
public class ErrorHandling extends
    ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<Webview_Main> {
        private Solo solo;
        private WebView web;
 ..
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(),getActivity());
}
```

Updated per recommendations (Currently - NullPointerException Erorrs)

```
public void testUrl() {
    String URL = solo.getString(com.example.webview.R.string.url);

         web = (WebView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.webview_main); //Added

    try {
    solo.assertCurrentActivity("Launching Main Activity", Webview_Main.class);
    assertTrue(solo.getWebUrl().equals("URL")); } 
    catch (Error error) {
}
}
public void testWeb() {
    try {
                    web = (WebView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.webview_main); //Added
        solo.getCurrentActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                web.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
            }
        });
        solo.sleep(1000);
    } catch (Error error) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

first, calling

```
web.getSettings();
```

gives you nothing. It provides you WebSettings, but you don't do anything with that object.

To assert current url in your webview you can use:

```
assertTrue(solo.getWebUrl().equals("your url"));
```

To load specified url in your webview you have to run it in another thread (here I'm not sure, if it should be runOnMainSync or runOnUiThread, however I tried runOnUiThread and it worked fine), for instance:

```
solo.getCurrentActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        web.loadUrl("http://www.OTHER_url_TO_test_AGAINST");
    }
});
```

Comment: I've added the tests above per your recommendations, Im getting NullPointerExceptions on both.

Comment: For the testWeb() my LogCat is saying its null at the web.loadUrl.

Comment: - if you are getting NullPointerExceptions probably webview is null. Make sure, that you have right reference for that object. 
- loadUrl is void method. What is null there?

Comment: Added refrenece to webview id. This resolved the testWeb test case, Thank you for that, However the TestUrl is still coming back null. any idea's.

Comment: I didn't test last version of robotium, however you can check it by self, if you have webview object: getUrl() - it returns current url. Make sure you run it on UI thread.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately i cannot seem to find a solution. Im getting Null on the the testURL, It seems the reference to the webview in the testWeb made it work fine.

Answer (score 1):

The steps to check the URL are as follows:

1) Create the webview object for the specific application

**obj = (WebView)getActivity().findViewById((package name of source or apk).R.id.(Id of the source webview))**

Note: If you dont have the source code of the source application of whome you are writing the test case then use the hierarchy viewer to find the id of the webview.

2) Add some sleep so that it will wait the time taken to load the url
**solo.sleep(time)**

3) Use this to get the current value or status of the application.
**obj.getSettings()**

4) Take a Boolean variable and store the value of 
**Boolean variable = solo.getWebUrl().equals("URL to be tested");**

5)  **assertTrue(Boolean variable)**
To verify the value true or false.